# how to store query result in a variable and dispaly it using classic ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, sql-server-2000

I'm using SQL server 2000 and classic ASP to display result using table i.e in HTML.
I'm trying to get the sum of value of a column records present in SQL table .
For that I tried this.

```
Balance Leave =<%
                        sql= "select SUM('no_of_leave_taken') from emp_leave_details where emp_no='"&request.QueryString("id")&"'"  
                        rs.open sql,con,1,2
                        response.Write(con.execute sql)
                        rs.close
                        %>
```

the error shown in the browser is

> The sum or average aggregate operation cannot take a varchar data type
>   as an argument.

Comment: @glenatron for what...sorry..

Comment: Being stuck using 15 year old technology that was barely fit for purpose back then...

Answer (score 2):

That looks like an SQL error - what happens if you run that query in the SQL Server Enterprise Manager? Is `emp_details.no_of_leave_taken` a numeric field?

One other thing I will add- **PLEASE DON'T EVER USE UNVERIFIED QUERYSTRING VALUES** - read [this ASP-friendly explanation of SQL Injection attacks](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150656/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/061902-1.shtml) for a bit of explanation on why.

Comment: I executed that query through enterprise manager....it gave result as numeric value...

Comment: Is the field of a numeric type?

Comment: I tried this instead, figured it out myself

    <%
          sql= "select SUM(no_of_leave_taken) as total from emp_leave_details where emp_name='"&request.QueryString("name")&"'" 
          rs.open sql,con,1,2
          response.Write(31- rs("total"))
          
          %>

It was something new for me to kow ...I was confused as the expression "total" in the above query worked for me and calling as a new column field virtually in the recordset using 

    rs("total")

thanks @glenatron for your help

Answer (score 1):

I tried this instead, figured it out myself `<% sql= "select SUM(no_of_leave_taken) as total from emp_leave_details where emp_name='"&request.QueryString("name")&"'" rs.open sql,con,1,2 response.Write(31- rs("total")) %>` It was something new for me to kow ...I was confused as the expression "total" in the above query worked for me and calling as a new column field virtually in the recordset using `rs("total")` thanks @glenatron for your help